# Testing method that uses Realm

Tags: android, mockito, realm, powermock, android-testing

I have a Database data source that is using Realm. So now I want to test that class but I'm facing some problems about how to use fixtures and how to mock Realm.
My database data source looks like:

```
public class DatabaseDataSource {
    private Realm realm;

    public DatabaseDataSource(Realm realm) {
        this.realm = realm;
    }


    public Observable<RealmResults> getContacts(String firstName, String lastName, String city, String zipCode) {

        final RealmQuery realmQuery = realm.where(Contact.class);
        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(firstName)) {
            realmQuery.contains("firstName", firstName);
        }
        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(lastName)) {
            realmQuery.contains("lastName", lastName));
        }
        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(city)) {
            realmQuery.contains("city", city);
        }
        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(zipCode)) {
            realmQuery.contains("zipCode", zipCode);
        }

        return realmQuery.findAll()
                    .asObservable();
    }
}
```

I'm using Robolectrics for other tests, and, in this case, I want to have a list of contacts in my mocked realm so I can check that filtering is working fine. How can I do that? 
I've tried doing:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(manifest=Config.NONE)
public class DatabaseDataSourceTest extends BaseTest {


    private DatabaseDataSource databaseDataSource;

    Realm realm;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {

        Realm.init(RuntimeEnvironment.application.getApplicationContext());
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(new RealmConfiguration.Builder().build());
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

        databaseDataSource = new DatabaseDataSource(realm);
    }

    @Test
    public void getContacts_filterByName() {
    databaseDataSource.getContacts("testName", null, null, null);
        // I don't know what to do here
    }

}
```

But I'm getting the following exception when doing:

```
Realm.init(RuntimeEnvironment.application.getApplicationContext());

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /var/folders/kc/76n8494x5cd2mtx340f27xch0000gn/T/android-tmp-robolectric409019390257818503/app_lib/librealm-jni.dylib
```

How should I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to run Unit test in Realm Db using Roboelectric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36715273/how-to-run-unit-test-in-realm-db-using-roboelectricRealm) says, that Roboelectric is not supported yet, so you can't use unit testing, only instrumented tests on real android device.

All tests can be run on a single thread, there is no need in rx in tests.

Answer (score 0):

https://medium.com/@q2ad/android-testing-realm-2dc1e1c94ee1 has a great solution: do not mock `Realm`, just use a temporary realm:

> ```
> RealmConfiguration testConfig = 
>    new RealmConfiguration.Builder().
>       inMemory().
>       name("test-realm").build();
>
> Realm testRealm = Realm.getInstance(testConfig);
> ```

Use this f.ex. in `@BeforeClass` (and remember to `testRealm.close()` in `@AfterClass` for good form).